# visual studio debug error unable to start program no more files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer, debugging

System info: Win 7 x64 SP 1, IE 10, Visual Studio 2010

I've been researching this error all over.

visual studio debug error:

```
"unable to start program (File path) no more files"
```

This started with the installation of internet explorer 10 and is happening across all my web projects within Visual Studio 2010.

I've tried all possible solutions (but not VS re-installs) from registry entries (http://forums.asp.net/t/1891930.aspx/1), IE 10 reinstall (fail...won't let me reinstall due to existing version) to switching default launch browser (in Visual Studio, select a different browser such as Chrome to be default browser in "Browse With..." option in project..it works but is pain in the rear) but one thing I just tried which is making me wonder if there is an issue with how IE 10 is launched came from the following experiment:

Basically I did the same process of changing the default browser except that I picked IE 10 x86 version manually in the "Browse With..." option, set it as default and ran project. Voila, it works with no issues.

My next step was to confirm the default IE option in the "Browse With...". I found articles such as (http://lennybacon.com/post/2010/08/22/rehowtochangethedefaultbrowserinvisualstudioprogrammatically) which put me on the path to find out where the settings are for Visual Studios default browser settings.

I checked the browser.xml file and all looked ok including the registry entry pointing to it. I'm unable to check the version of the browser since MS, in it's infinite wisdom decided not to show that info in the Help -> About or anywhere else. so my gut feeling is that the default IE 10 being launched is the x64 bit version.

Does anyone know?
1) how I can confirm the default version of IE 10 launched since afore methods have not worked and 
2) why would (I'm assuming) IE 10 x64 launch vs. the defined IE 10 x86 referenced version in the browser.xml file?

Thanks for any and all help.
Dave

**UPDATE:**

So from doing continual testing, it seems that after I ran the process to change the Default Browser settings in both the registry and the browser.xml file, upon launching the debug process in Visual Studio 2010, it automatically reverted back to the original default broswer settings which would launch the x64 version of IE 10. So in my case, it seems that the issue (error above) lies in the fact that debugging in Visual Studio 2010 using x64 browsers would cause the error. With no recourse, I ended up removing IE 10 from Windows Features and going through a painful process of getting IE 9 back on my system, I now can effectively debug using IE (x86).

It seems that MS is not pursuing any fixes for this issue of the default browser in VS 2010 from what I've read. There are in browser tools I've seen to do the default browser setting changes but don't want to bother with it/don't trust it will work.

Hopfully this helps others dealing with the same pain I have endured...

Thanks

Dave

Comment: you can uninstall IE10 and return to IE9 if you go Installed Updated and select to uninstall IE10

Comment: Hey Alex...unfortunately, IE 10 does not appear in the "Programs and Features" option which is making me think it's a bad install yet it is referenced in the "Windows Features"...hmmm. Guess I could try "Disable" and reinstall to see what happens but was looking for more solid solution/resolution...Thanks

Comment: yes, it's not present in "Programs and Features", only in installed updates. But I uninstalled it without problem and how use IE9 for debugging with VS2010.

Comment: Adding x86 version of IE10 through VS BrowseWith dialog did fix the problem. Though I didn't do anything in .xml or registry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I ran into this problem (using IE 11) I noticed that iexplore was open about a hundred times in the task manager. After killing them all I was able to open my project just fine.

Since then, I have made a .bat file with this code: taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe /T

so now I just run the .bat when I get that error. (alternatively you could run that code from the cmd)

Answer (score 1):

James Butler's response is good for killing all the open IE processes. Which seems to be the issue here. The best solution I have been using is to just set, "Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application." then I just refresh the URL (if already open in browser) each time I rerun the debugger.

Access in *Project* properties under the, "Web" option. Then change setting there. [image]

Comment: So here, url would just be localhost:5000/

Answer (score 0):

Check the following registry key

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth

Make sure that the value is **Minimum**

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error today after restarting from a Windows Update.  I'm on Windows 8.1 desktop using VS.NET 2013.  To fix I had to add another browser choice in VS debug that was pointing to the x86 version of IE11, and set that as the default.  Although the post alludes to the x64 vs x86 browsers being the issue, this seems like an easier solution than the original poster's process of uninstalling and reinstalling browsers.

This blog explains how to set the default browser for debugging to IE x86: http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/visual-studio-web-developer-express-starting-two-instances-of-internet-explorer-and-throwing-an-error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: "...try selecting the project node in Solution Explorer and choose Set as StartUp Project". Just worked for me.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/efd93f22-1f1f-4fb1-8ff3-e29104780572/unable-to-start-program-there-are-no-more-files?forum=lightswitchgeneral

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by a more general issue of low available system memory.  In my case, Performance Monitor showed I was using 82% of my available memory when I was receiving the error.  Looking at the processes, the culprit for me was lots of Chrome processes.  I shut down Chrome, which freed up about 2 GB of memory, and then I was able to run the debugger successfully.  Shutting down lots of IE processes would achieve the same thing of freeing up lots of memory.  So I think the solution is just to free up system memory by shutting down whatever processes you don't need open.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is working for me with windows 11 and edge:

- Project Start Options - Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an
  external application.
- Start - Local IIS (Microsoft Edge)/Script
  debugging disabled
- Create a shortcut to launch the application like
  this: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
  http://localhost/MyApplication/